# А command to delete files older than X days, but leave the last 2 files

Tags: bash

I need help with the command to delete files on the server.

I have some archive folder.
file names of the form app-XXXXXX.tar.gz, where XXXXXX is the backup date. For example, app-231019.tar.gz

I need to delete files older than 14 days, but not the last 2 files.

I found a command

```
find /folder +14 -type f -delete
```

but it is not suitable for me

1. The filter "older than 14 days" should be applied based on the file name, and not by the date of recording to the server.
2. I cannot find a command on how to set a limit so that the last 2 files are not deleted, even if they are older than 14 days.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". You haven't showed us what you tried writing except for a most rudimentary attempt. Please give it more research and effort before asking, then follow the suggestion in "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".

Comment: what server are you talking about?

Comment: Ruby has multiple ways of doing a recursive-descent through a directory or it can simply grab filenames, in the current directory. Parse the name, see if it's older than n days, delete it if it is. It's not hard.

Comment: can you send me a link for example plz?

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
dir="dir"   # replace with your pathname
fortnightago=$(awk 'BEGIN {print strftime("%y%m%d", systime() - 86400 * 14)}')
# If your date command supports -d option, you can also say as:
# fortnightago=$(date -d "14 days ago" +%y%m%d)

for i in "$dir"/app-*.tar.gz; do
    if [[ $i =~ app-([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})\.tar\.gz ]]; then
        yy="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
        mm="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        dd="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        if (( $yy$mm$dd <= $fortnightago )); then
            printf "%d%d%d%c%s\n" "${yy#0}" "${mm#0}" "${dd#0}" $'\t' "$i"
        fi
    fi
done | sort -rn -k1 | tail -n +3 | cut -f 2 | xargs rm --
```

**[Explanation]**

- First it extracts the date string and rearrange it in "%y%m%d" order
  for numeric comparison.
- Print filenames which are older than 14 days with adding the date
  in the 1st field.
- Then sort the filenames by the 1st field in the descending order (the latest file first).
- Then skip the first two lines to keep them.
- Cut out the filenames as a removing list.
- The filenames are passed to `xargs` with `rm` command.

As an alternative, if `perl` is your option, you can say:

```
perl -e '
    $dir = "dir";
    @t = localtime(time() - 86400 * 14);
    $fortnightago = sprintf("%02d%02d%02d", $t[5] - 100, $t[4] + 1, $t[3]);
    @ary = map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] }
    grep { $_->[1] <= $fortnightago }
    map { [ $_, m/app-(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\.tar\.gz/ && "$3$2$1" ] }
    (<$dir/app-*.tar.gz>);
    unlink splice(@ary, 2);
'
```

Hope this helps.